# Android Studio is deleting settings.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

### The problem

I've noticed on this last update of Android Studio (2.1.2) that my `settings.gradle` file keeps getting deleted and I have to either create a new one or to copy it back from some backup or version control.

When this happens, my project breaks, it becomes unable to sync the files with gradle and nothing works until I solve this issue.

My project is using gradle 2.1.2, like this:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
```

This is my `settings.gradle` file:

```
include ':app', ':slider'
project(':slider').projectDir = new File('/some/path/on/my/disk')
```

**Edit:** This is how my project looks like after the file gets deleted.

[image]

Is there anything that changed lately on AS that is causing this behavior? Do I have to change something on the settings?

### What I've tried so far

- I've already tried to put a new `settings.gradle` file, it keeps getting deleted from time to time;
- I have reinstalled Android Studio from scratch, no effect.

Comment: I have the same version (2.1.2), But it didn't delete settings.gradle, I did update it from stable channel.

Comment: I noticed that it's happening after I open that file. I'm not sure why this is happening, but it's happening on two computers here. (A Macbook pro and a Windows PC)

Comment: Then Maybe it is a bug!